# My sprite doesn't detect touch during its movement with CCAction

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, touch, sprite

My problem is: When I creat a sprite at a specific position and with `CCActionMoveTo`, I made it to move another position. During its movement the sprite detect touch events . But when I touch my sprite during the movement it doesn't work:

```
-(void)caca
{
    target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"boulerouge_06.png"];
    target.position=(300,10);
    [self addChild:target];

    id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 
                                        position:ccp(240, 160)];
    [target runAction:actionMove];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprites don't detect touch events. You need to create a control layer and they can then tell your sprites to do something else via your game layer.

Comment: ok so is there a tutorial for it or maybe you have some code to explain me more please :)

Comment: There's lots of Cocos2D tutorials around. Have a look at Ray Wenderlich website for example.